# Adding an Audience list to a campaign using google ads API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to attach an audience list - which I have already created on Google ads using the python api - to an existing campaign on the same Google ads account. I have both the ID of the campaign and the ID of the audience list, but I did not find any clear example in the documentation on how to attach an audience list to campaign.

Can anyone provide example on how the json object to be sent to google ads is structured to request adding an audience list to a campaign?

I tried to follow the reference guidelines in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/CampaignCriterionService.CampaignCriterion) to compose the request json format object needed to be sent to add an audience list to a certain campaign .

And also searched for similar problems, found this [solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/rxKnXiJtfl4) in Java,but I did not succeed into coming up with a similar one in python.

```py
from googleads import adwords
import yaml

data = {} # should contain credentials for authentication

auth_data = yaml.dump(data)
client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromString(auth_data)

campaign_criterion_list_service = client.GetService(
    'CampaignCriterionService', version='v201809')

 operations = [ 
    { 
        'operand': { 
            'campaignId': 1982314222, # some campaign in my account

            'criterion': { 
                'type': 'USER_LIST',
                'id': 823895895,# an existing audience list on my  google ads account
            }, 
            'campaignCriterionStatus': 'ACTIVE' 
        }, 
        'operator': 'ADD', 
    } 
 ]
campaign_criterion_list_service.mutate(operations)
```

But it fails providing the error

```
GoogleAdsServerFault: [CampaignCriterionError.CONCRETE_TYPE_REQUIRED @ operations[0].operand.criterion]
```

I expected the audience list to be added to the campaign and return a success code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out . Just needed to adjust the naming of the expected fields

```
campaign_criterion_list_service = client.GetService(
    'CampaignCriterionService', version='v201809')

 operations = [ 
    { 
        'operand': { 
            'campaignId': 1764074348, 

            'criterion': { 
                'xsi_type': 'CriterionUserList',
                'type': 'USER_LIST',
                'userListId': 823895895,
                'userListEligibleForDisplay': True,
                'userListEligibleForSearch': True
            }, 
            'campaignCriterionStatus': 'ACTIVE' 
        }, 
        'operator': 'ADD', 
    } 
 ]
```